# Add icon CKEditor in Liferay

Tags: ckeditor, liferay, wysiwyg

I'm adding an image to the CKEditor in Liferay. I have modified the hook of CKEditor and I get the new button. But I have a problem when adding a new image downloaded to the icon, I am unable to recognize the wysiwing.

[image: Eclipse command]

The problem seems (`?t=F0EM`) is generated automatically. How I can remove it for this special case? Without this command (queryString), the image loads without problem:

[image: no picture]

Could anyone help? thank you!

greetings from Spain